# Model Rocket Launch Control Panel

Tags: power, led, layout

The momentary push button switches have LEDs integrated in them with resistors for 12v, the wires on top of them are wired to the LED inside them.
My goal is to be able to deactivate the two safety switches, and the ARM light to come on and a buzzer to sound.  When pressing the ARM button, my goal is for the FIRE light to come on, and when pressed, send a large amount of current through R1, heating it up and lighting a match.

Does this look correct?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can show the LEDs and dropping resistors as separate components in the schematic diagram ... it would make a clearer diagram

Comment: it does not look "correct" ... the power supply voltage is too low ... the speaker requires a device that generates a sound signal

Comment: yikes, i did this quickly.  i meant to have 9v by connecting the negative terminals of two 9v batteries as well as the positive terminals for optimal current.  also the speaker is a buzzer.

Comment: None of these are sensitive or expensive components. I would recommend getting some alligator clips and just trying it out. You can use an incandescent bulb to simulate an igniter, or just burn a few testing. Beware that a LED uses a lot less current than the igniter, so it's not a good stand in.

Comment: Rather than screencap the schematic editor, you can simply hit "save" and the live schematic will drop into your post in editable form.

Answer (score 1):

Generally correct. Some things:

(and assuming you mean "deactivate the two safety switches")

- the buzzer should go between the `arm` & `safe` switches if it is to buzz when key & safe switches are closed
- make sure the polarity of the LEDs in the switches is correct

But - seems like would be desirable to buzz when arm, safe and key are ALL closed?  In that case the buzzer is in the correct place as-is.

Nice project.

Comment: Youre right, it probably would be better to do it that way.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version of the schematic.

[image]